# How do you convert a local file path into an assembly based one?

Tags: c#, wpf, path, uri

I made my first ever game in C# using WPF (clone of Flappy Bird), here's the Codebehind:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace FlappyBirdWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        private readonly MediaPlayer player2 = new MediaPlayer();
        private readonly DispatcherTimer gameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private readonly Random pipePos = new Random();
        private double highscore = double.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\highscore.txt"));
        private double score, counter = 5;
        private int gravity = 8;
        private Rect birdHitbox;
        private bool isGameOver;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            gameTimer.Tick += MainEventTimer;
            gameTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            StartGame();
        }

        private void MainEventTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtScore.Content = $"Score: {score}";
            txtHighscore.Content = $"Highscore: {highscore}";
            gameOver.Content = "";

            birdHitbox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(bird), Canvas.GetTop(bird), bird.Width - 12, bird.Height - 15);

            Canvas.SetTop(bird, Canvas.GetTop(bird) + gravity);

            if (Canvas.GetTop(bird) < -10 || Canvas.GetTop(bird) > 370) EndGame();

            foreach (var img in MyCanvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
            {

                if ((string)img.Tag == "obs1" || (string)img.Tag == "obs2" || (string)img.Tag == "obs3")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, Canvas.GetLeft(img) - counter);
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(img) < -60)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(img, 800);

                        if ((string)img.Tag == "obs1")
                        {
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs1Top, pipePos.Next(150, 350) * -1);
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs1Bot, Canvas.GetTop(obs1Top) + 500);
                        }
                        if ((string)img.Tag == "obs2")
                        {
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs2Top, pipePos.Next(150, 350) * -1);
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs2Bot, Canvas.GetTop(obs2Top) + 500);
                        }
                        if ((string)img.Tag == "obs3")
                        {
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs3Top, pipePos.Next(150, 350) * -1);
                            Canvas.SetTop(obs3Bot, Canvas.GetTop(obs3Top) + 500);
                        }
                        counter += 0.1;
                        score += 0.5;
                        player2.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\audio\blip.wav"));
                        player2.Play();
                    }

                    Rect pipeHitbox = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(img), Canvas.GetTop(img), img.Width, img.Height);

                    if (birdHitbox.IntersectsWith(pipeHitbox)) EndGame();
                }

                if ((string)img.Tag == "cloud")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, Canvas.GetLeft(img) - 2);

                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(img) < -250) Canvas.SetLeft(img, 550);
                }

                if ((string)img.Tag == "ground")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, Canvas.GetLeft(img) - counter);
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(img) < -525)
                    {
                        if (img.Name == "ground1") Canvas.SetLeft(img, 510);
                        if (img.Name == "ground2") Canvas.SetLeft(img, Canvas.GetLeft(ground1) + 524);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void KeyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Space && !isGameOver)
            {
                bird.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(-20, bird.Width / 2, bird.Height / 2);
                gravity = -8;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.R)
            {
                StartGame();
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Escape && isGameOver)
            {
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        private void KeyIsUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            bird.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(5, bird.Width / 2, bird.Height / 2);
            gravity = 8;
        }

        private void StartGame()
        {
            MyCanvas.Focus();
            player.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\audio\bgm.wav"));
            player.Play();
            bird.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"assets/images/bird.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            isGameOver = false;
            score = 0;
            counter = 5;
            int cloudGap = 250;
            Canvas.SetTop(bird, 190);

            foreach (var img in MyCanvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
            {
                if ((string)img.Tag == "obs1") Canvas.SetLeft(img, 500);
                if ((string)img.Tag == "obs2") Canvas.SetLeft(img, 800);
                if ((string)img.Tag == "obs3") Canvas.SetLeft(img, 1100);

                if ((string)img.Tag == "cloud")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, 250 + cloudGap);
                    cloudGap = 850;
                }

                if (img.Name == "ground1")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
                }
                if (img.Name == "ground2")
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img, 520);
                }
            }

            gameTimer.Start();
        }

        private void EndGame()
        {

            if (score > highscore)
            {
                highscore = score;
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\highscore.txt"))
                {
                    file.Write(highscore.ToString());
                }
            }
            player.Stop();
            player.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\audio\boom.wav"));
            player.Play();
            gameTimer.Stop();
            isGameOver = true;
            bird.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"assets/images/deadBird.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            gameOver.Content = "                Game over! \n       Press 'R' to play again.\n" +
                "...or press 'Esc' to quit... loser.";
        }
    }
}
```

In some instances you can see I was able to successfully use something like `$"assets/images/deadBird.png"` to reference a file without specifying the entire local path, but in some cases I wasn't allowed to do that and had to use the full path like `@"C:\Users\nikan\source\repos\Flappy Cat\Flappy Cat\assets\audio\boom.wav"`. Is there a workaround to this? Any suggestions are appreciated, I've only been working in c# for ~2 months!

Comment: Why are you using Uri in all those places?

Comment: Files that are assets are normally located relative to the executables, and not in the current working directory. You have to find a way to get the directory where your executable is located (maybe Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), and then use the functions in System.IO.Path to form the path to the files (Combine, GetFullPath, GetDirectoryName, etc). Experiment your way forward. Don't hardcode slash.

Comment: The current working directory is supposed to be controlled by the user of the application, and not the developer. Only files that the user is supposed to work with and perhaps modify, not supplied with the app (e.g. a Word document for the Word application, an Excel file for the Excel application, any movie file for a movie player) are supposed to be handled through the current working directory. The current working directory can be changed to whatever the user chooses. Don't mess with the current working directory programmatically, unless it is to help the user find the user's own files.

Comment: The read-only files that gets deployed with your program will normally be located relative to your executable, perhaps in a subfolder. The current working directory and the executables directory often happen to be the same folder when you start an application during development, but don't let that fool you into making a flawed app.

Answer (score 0):

It may be suitable:

```
using System.IO;

player.Open(new Uri($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\assets\\audio\\boom.wav"));
```